# Как выполнить функцию в данном случаи?

Tags: javascript

Как делать что бы функция отправляла результат единожды? Надо отправлять в сокет статус пользователя. Если пользователь перемещает курсор у него один статус. Если пользователь отошел через некоторое время у него появляется другой статус.
Пробую писать функцию. Функция sleep срабатывает как нужно данные отправляются один раз. Вот проблема в другой функции как её так же отправлять единожды? По тому как начинаешь двигать мышкой функция выполняется многократно. А мне нужно отправить в сокет что пользователь на месте только один раз. Как её запускать единожды для отправки в websocket? Вот мой пример кода:

```
let times = 1000;
let timet = null;
function resetTi() {
    clearTimeout(timet);
    console.log('on site');
    timet = setTimeout(sleep, times);
}
function sleep() {
    console.log('sleep');
}
document.addEventListener('mousemove', resetTi);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let times = 1000;
let timet = null;
function resetTi() {
  if (!timet) {
    // отправить в сокет что пользователь на месте
  }
  clearTimeout(timet);
  console.log('on site');
  timet = setTimeout(sleep, times);
}
function sleep() {
  timet = null;
  console.log('sleep');
}
document.addEventListener('mousemove', resetTi);
```

Comment: В ответе функция sleep не отрабатывает но суть примерно ясна!!!

Comment: @МестныйДьявол да, поправил

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь!!!!

Answer (score 0):

всё намного проще

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', resetTi, {
  once: true
});
```

но можно вообще этого не делать, на сервере есть такое понятие как время сессии. если нет взаимодействия клиента с сервером(время сессии заканчивается) - отправлять клиенту команду  перехода на страницу авторизации (к примеру)

Comment: Это понятно!!! Цель другая. Эта клиентская часть для чата. Если пользователь не передвигает мышку, по задумке 20 секунд то в сокет отправляется что пользователь спит!!! А дальше все как вы правильно сказали если пользователь отсутствует более 5 минут то здесь как раз через время сессии!!! Чисто клиент для взаимодействия с клиентом!!!

Comment: @Местный Дьявол проще по setInterval проверять координаты мыши и если они совпадают с предыдущими - значит клиент спит...